# Clicking Facebook 'like' button does not then show on likers timeline/wall

Tags: web, facebook-like

I've added a facebook like button to my website (code below) but when that button is clicked to 'like' it doesn't show up on the timeline. I've tested in on various accounts, making sure that the relevant settings are correct. I believe it may be because the website name has a hyphen in it (i.e www.site-name.co.uk) as I wasn't allowed to use and associated email address (i.e admin@site-name.co.uk) when trying to create a facebook page (the response returned was something along the lines of ;this is not a proper email address').

Any clues as if I'm doing something wrong?? Thanks in advance.

Code I'm using:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.band-scene.co.uk&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;action=like&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;  height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the 'Like' button will only add the page to the users 'Likes' section on their profile, which may or may not show on their timeline.
If the use adds a comment when they Like it, then it will show on their timeline.

However as you are using the iframe version of the Like button, I'm not sure if the Comments box will show for that.   When using the fb:like markup, a box appears under the button to allow the user to enter a comment.